# popup menu проблема с иконками

Tags: android

Есть кнопка, при нажатие на которую должно всплывать popup menu, все нормально получается, но вот иконки не отображаются.
Как я понял android принципиально не хочет их там отображать, вроде как даже защищенное свойство класса есть которое запрещает их.
И собственно вопрос как с наименьшими костылями мне сделать это меню, самым простым наверное можно использовать какую библиотеку для этого, я использовал вот эту https://github.com/shehabic/Droppy но там нет событий сокрытия окна и настройки позиций этого окна.
Не знаю может быть и spinner для этого дела подойдет?

Как вы решаете эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы можете использовать виджет [`PopupWindow`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html), который позволяет разместить в попап-окне любые виджеты, в том числе и `ImageView`, так же, как и скомпоновать их любым возможным способом.
Класс имеет метод `showAtLocation()` для позиционирования на экране, метод `isShowing()`- индикатор, что попап отображается и множество других методов.

Для меню с иконками вы можете использовать несколько горизонтальных `LinearLayout` с картинкой и текстом и сгруппировать их в вертикальный `LinearLayout` или использовать контейнеры табличной верстки, вроде `TableLayout` или другой доступный вам способ.

Обсуждение на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454995/popupmenu-with-icons)

Comment: Да похоже, быстрее будет допилить ту библиотеку что использую...